# How to get value from json data to input

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I tried to get value from JSON data to my input using jquery autocomplete. But it seems my code isn't working. I want when I type the province name it shows up then when I select the province name will also get the id and then put in the input value for province_id.

view code:

```
<input type="text" id="province" name="province" id="province" class="form-control col-md-10"
                placeholder="Province Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control>
```

autocomplete :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
$("#province").autocomplete({
  source: data,
  select: function(event, ui){
    $('[name="province"]').val(ui.item.province);
    $('[name="province_id"]').val(ui.item.province_id)
  }
});
```

var data :

```
[{"province_id":"1","province":"Bali"},{"province_id":"2","province":"Bangka Belitung"},{"province_id":"3","province":"Banten"},{"province_id":"4","province":"Bengkulu"},{"province_id":"5","province":"DI Yogyakarta"},{"province_id":"6","province":"DKI Jakarta"},{"province_id":"7","province":"Gorontalo"},{"province_id":"8","province":"Jambi"},{"province_id":"9","province":"Jawa Barat"},{"province_id":"10","province":"Jawa Tengah"},{"province_id":"11","province":"Jawa Timur"},{"province_id":"12","province":"Kalimantan Barat"},{"province_id":"13","province":"Kalimantan Selatan"},{"province_id":"14","province":"Kalimantan Tengah"},{"province_id":"15","province":"Kalimantan Timur"},{"province_id":"16","province":"Kalimantan Utara"},{"province_id":"17","province":"Kepulauan Riau"},{"province_id":"18","province":"Lampung"},{"province_id":"19","province":"Maluku"},{"province_id":"20","province":"Maluku Utara"},{"province_id":"21","province":"Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)"},{"province_id":"22","province":"Nusa Tenggara Barat (NTB)"},{"province_id":"23","province":"Nusa Tenggara Timur (NTT)"},{"province_id":"24","province":"Papua"},{"province_id":"25","province":"Papua Barat"},{"province_id":"26","province":"Riau"},{"province_id":"27","province":"Sulawesi Barat"},{"province_id":"28","province":"Sulawesi Selatan"},{"province_id":"29","province":"Sulawesi Tengah"},{"province_id":"30","province":"Sulawesi Tenggara"},{"province_id":"31","province":"Sulawesi Utara"},{"province_id":"32","province":"Sumatera Barat"},{"province_id":"33","province":"Sumatera Selatan"},{"province_id":"34","province":"Sumatera Utara"}];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQueryUI autocomplete `source` property only accepts data in a specific format. It needs to be an array of objects with at least `label` and `value` properties. You need to amend your `data` variable to be in this format.

I would suggest doing this in your `$results` variable coming from PHP, however if it's not possible to achieve then you can use the `map()` method of the array instead. Note that you need to update the properties of `ui.item` that you use to set the field values because of this change.

Finally, note that I used `id` selectors for the fields as there are present on the elements already, and simpler and faster than attribute selectors.

```js
var data = [{"province_id":"1","province":"Bali"},{"province_id":"2","province":"Bangka Belitung"},{"province_id":"3","province":"Banten"},{"province_id":"4","province":"Bengkulu"},{"province_id":"5","province":"DI Yogyakarta"},{"province_id":"6","province":"DKI Jakarta"},{"province_id":"7","province":"Gorontalo"},{"province_id":"8","province":"Jambi"},{"province_id":"9","province":"Jawa Barat"},{"province_id":"10","province":"Jawa Tengah"},{"province_id":"11","province":"Jawa Timur"},{"province_id":"12","province":"Kalimantan Barat"},{"province_id":"13","province":"Kalimantan Selatan"},{"province_id":"14","province":"Kalimantan Tengah"},{"province_id":"15","province":"Kalimantan Timur"},{"province_id":"16","province":"Kalimantan Utara"},{"province_id":"17","province":"Kepulauan Riau"},{"province_id":"18","province":"Lampung"},{"province_id":"19","province":"Maluku"},{"province_id":"20","province":"Maluku Utara"},{"province_id":"21","province":"Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)"},{"province_id":"22","province":"Nusa Tenggara Barat (NTB)"},{"province_id":"23","province":"Nusa Tenggara Timur (NTT)"},{"province_id":"24","province":"Papua"},{"province_id":"25","province":"Papua Barat"},{"province_id":"26","province":"Riau"},{"province_id":"27","province":"Sulawesi Barat"},{"province_id":"28","province":"Sulawesi Selatan"},{"province_id":"29","province":"Sulawesi Tengah"},{"province_id":"30","province":"Sulawesi Tenggara"},{"province_id":"31","province":"Sulawesi Utara"},{"province_id":"32","province":"Sumatera Barat"},{"province_id":"33","province":"Sumatera Selatan"},{"province_id":"34","province":"Sumatera Utara"}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  let newData = data.map(o => ({ label: o.province, value: o.province_id }));

  $("#province").autocomplete({
    source: newData,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#province').val(ui.item.label);
      $('#province_id').val(ui.item.value)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<input type="text" id="province" name="province" id="province" class="form-control col-md-10" placeholder="Province Name" />
<input type="text" name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control" />
```